# mysql trigger variables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

In MYSQL, how do you assign a field name `fname` from the table `ftable` to a variable within a trigger query?

I am aware of mysql global variables: `@@`
Local Variables? `@`

But is that even the right syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You can just assign it from the field right in the select; it would get the last selected value if several rows are returned.

```
SELECT @tmp:=fvalue FROM ftable WHERE ...
```

A simple [SQLfiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25977/1).

Comment: Actually lets assume we don't know what the field value is. We only know a field name. My question confused that, let me fix it.

Assuming it is field name not field value.. Will that statement result in a variable `@tmp` having the value of `fname` that I can use in the rest of the trigger script?

Comment: @SofianeMerah If fvalue is a field name, `@tmp` will have the value of that field. That is, if `ftable` has only one row where the field value of `fvalue` is 1, `@tmp` will contain the value 1.

Comment: hmm I tried using @tmp as a variable in `INSERT INTO @tmp VALUES (8)`. But it didn't work. @tmp was assigned the value `table2`. I get a schema creation error.